# Why did McCoy and Crusher go on Away Missions?

Tags: star-trek

Not all the time, of course, but it seems odd in retrospect as the chief medical officer should be considered too indispensable to risk on a surface mission-McCoy literally risks his life in several TOS episodes, for example.

Comment: You could say the same about Kirk, Worf and the rest. No real life crew of that size would risk it's most senior commanders on away missions. There would be plenty of experienced mid level leaders to head up most missions, the senior command only involved for strategic decision making and diplomatic away missions. So... dramatic purposes?

Comment: “the chief medical officer should be considered too indispensable to risk on a surface mission” — why? Voyager survived seven years in the Delta Quadrant with a backup AI doctor and an incompetent nurse.

Comment: I humoured that in some cases, if there's a chance of running into the locals, it would be diplomatically more appealing to be greeted by senior staff rather than the interns.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I was just going to say Kes was a very good nurse in my opinion, but then I remembered Tom and that's probably who you meant